Authorization header is not send on redirect
I am trying to redirect to a new location and passing the authorization bearer. But it seems that the bearer token is not send.
I am doing this in my php code
header('Authorization: Bearer ' . $retval); 
header('Location:http://nextsite.com/home/index', true, 301); 
                    
exit();

I have enabled the Authorization in my .htaccess file
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0

And I am able to call the site with a cURL call where bearer token is send trough without problems.
I am running php version 8.3
Server version: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2024-07-17T18:57:26
I have tried many things, change the order of the header calls, the capitalization of the authorization/bearer without any lock.

Authorization is a request header. It makes no sense to send it with response. Your browser just ignores it.

What you are doing with this code is sending response headers to the browser. You are not sending anything to any server.
The second line
header('Location:http://nextsite.com/home/index', true, 301);

tells the browser that it is supposed to send a GET request to the given URL (btw: there should be a space between "Location:" and "http..."). The Authorization header line will very likely be ignored. At least, I never heard of browsers taking this into account. I also think it's a serious security risk to send auth tokens in response headers to the browser.
And one more hint: The browser may follow the given redirect URL or not. You can't rely on this.
